# c# HttpWebRequest get error 500 but in browsers is correct

Tags: c#

when i use this code i get error 500

this url when send on respoce redirect to another url

but on redirect request type is Post

```
WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.khanoumi.com/brandproductlist/allajax?id=204");
req.Method = "GET";
string response = "";
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
{
    response = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

but when i open this url in browser it is correct

Comment: Your URL is incorrect: "http://www.khanoumi.com//brandproductlist/allajax?id=204" note the double slash after "khanoumi.com".

Comment: i fixed tanks ,
but the problem had not be solved yet

Comment: so why this url get response in browser

Comment: because type of new url is "post" with some data

Comment: Are you not sitting on a network with a proxy perhaps? If you are change your system.net config to use the default proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1 :** make request to the url disabling the auto redirection, we will get the redirection url and cookie from the header of the response

```
string host = "http://www.khanoumi.com";
WebHeaderCollection headers;
string response = "";

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create ("http://www.khanoumi.com/brandproductlist/allajax?id=204");
req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
req.Method = "GET";
req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
req.Headers.Add ("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36";

// reading the response
HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse ();
//getting new url and cookie of the header
headers = res.Headers;
string newUrl = host + headers.Get ("location");
string cookie = headers.Get("Set-Cookie").Split(';')[0];
```

**Step 2 :** make a request to the new url with the new cookie

```
HttpWebRequest req2 = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create (newUrl);
req2.Method = "GET";
req2.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
req2.KeepAlive = true;
req2.Headers.Add ("Cookie", cookie);
req2.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
req2.Headers.Add ("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
req2.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36";
try{
    res = (HttpWebResponse)req2.GetResponse ();
    headers = res.Headers;
    foreach (string key in headers.AllKeys) {
        Console.WriteLine (key + ":" + headers.Get (key));
    }
    // you will get your result html in response variable
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream())){
        response = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }           
    Console.WriteLine (response);

}catch(WebException ex){
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream())){
        response = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }           
    Console.WriteLine (response);
    Console.WriteLine (ex.Response);
}
```

**Note:  the user-agent header is needed here, the redirect url checks for its presence and it was the main reason for 500**